# How to I make a "select case"-like operation in reactor

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

I am making a discord bot that needs to read a list of arguments, and with the first argument given, have it determine which branch to run.

Something kinda like this.

```
Mono.just(stringList)
.ifSelectmap(conditional1, branch1)
.ifSelectmap(conditional2, branch2)
.ifSelectmap(conditional3, branch3)
// non branch logic here
```

The only way I can figure out to do anything like this would just cause several deeply nested switchIfEmpty statements. Which would be hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

if the conditional logic doesn't involve latency-heavy operations (ie performing IO), then there is nothing wrong in passing a more fleshed out `Function` to `map`/`flatMap`.
I'm going to assume your "branches" are actually asynchronous operations represented as a `Mono<R>` or `Flux<R>` (that is, all the branches share the same return type `R`), so we're talking `flatMap`:

```
Flux<V> source; //...
Flux<R> result = source.flatMap(v -> {
    if (conditional1) return branch1(v);
    if (conditional2) return branch2(v);
    if (conditional3) return branch3(v);
    return Mono.empty(); //no conditional match == ignore
    //you might want a default processing instead for the above
};
```

Comment: You're right all but one, incorrect syntax, would involve io.